# C# OData update untracked entity without retrieving it from database

Tags: c#, odata, uwp

I have a local SQLite database in my Universal Windows Application and I want to update some changes in an entity to a REST-API Server with OData. 
When I try to update just using:

```
context.UpdateObject(entity);
context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get an error that says:

> The context is not currently tracking the entity.

I know I can get the entity from the server, update it and save again but that means that I have to manually copy all the attributes of my local entity to the one obtained from the server. **Also I don't think it's efficient to read an entire entity from the server every time I want to update**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Update - The context is not currently tracking the entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547783/entity-framework-update-the-context-is-not-currently-tracking-the-entity)

Comment: Hi Mark, I don't think it is duplicate because in that answer they use a database query to solve the reference problem, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: How did you retrieved it ? and no they are not using a query to solve it, the usage of that query is the problem in the other Question.

Comment: I don't retrieve it, that is what I want to avoid because that means that every time I want to update I need to retrieve the entire entity from the server. I think it should be a better way because I have the Id of the entity, it should be enough to update. Thank you for help clarifying the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error `The context is not currently tracking the entity.` said, the problem here is that your `entity` is not tracked by your `context`.

From the [tutorial](http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#04-01-basic-crud-operations), we can find following notes under **Update an entity**:

> The `context` will track all the changes you make to the entities attached to it (by getting `person` from the service you attached it to the `context`) and will send requests for the changes when `SaveChanges` is called.

So by default, entities returned by queries are tracked. And thus, the changes of these entities can be sent back to the data service when we call `DataServiceContext.SaveChangesAsync` method. But since your entity is not retrieved by queries, you would get this error while calling `SaveChangesAsync` method.

To solve this issue, we can use `DataServiceContext.AttachTo` method to attach the entity. If we use `DataServiceContext.AttachTo` to attach an entity, `DataServiceContext` will track the entity. Following is a simple sample:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var context = new DefaultContainer(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/v4/(S(lqbvtwide0ngdev54adgc0lu))/TripPinServiceRW/"));

    var person = new Person
    {
        UserName = "russellwhyte",
        FirstName = "Jay",
        LastName = "Zuo"
    };

    context.AttachTo("People", person, "*");

    context.UpdateObject(person);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var personUpdated = await context.People.ByKey("russellwhyte").GetValueAsync();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{personUpdated.UserName} : {personUpdated.FirstName} {personUpdated.LastName}");
}
```

For more info, please see [Client Tracking](http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#04-09-client-tracking).

Comment: You saved my day, Thank you so much!!!!! Could I ask you if additional to the documentation, Do you read any additional resource?

Comment: I read the [Getting Started](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/) of  OData and some other tutorial especially OData Client for .NET tutorial at [Microsoft OData stack](http://odata.github.io/).

Comment: This worked for me:
Before the line of `context.Updateobject(person);`, write the line: `context.Attach(person);`